# Error 500 when I try to store data from Vue.JS by Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have an issue with my code. When I try to store data using Vue.JS and Laravel i get error 500 in the console. I'm stuck on it for 6 hours.

Controller
- DashboardAdvantagesController.php:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
      $request->validate([
          'icon'=> 'required',
          'title'=> 'required'
      ]);

      $advantage = $request->HomepageAdvantages()->create([
          'icon'=> $request->icon,
          'title'=> $request->title
      ]);

      return response()->json([
         'advantage'=> $advantage,
         'message'=> 'task has been created!'
      ]);

  }
```

Model
- HomepageAdvantages

```
class HomepageAdvantages extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
      'icon', 'title', 'text',
  ];
}
```

API route

```
Route::post('/advantages/store', 'DashboardAdvantagesController@store');
```

Vue Component

```
  createAdvantage(){

   console.log(this.advantage.icon);
   console.log(this.advantage.title);


   axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/advantages/store', {icon: this.advantage.icon, 
    title: this.advantage.title})

     .then(response=>{
     this.advantages.push(response.data.advantage);

                })

              .catch(error=>{

                console.log(error);

                });
                console.log(response.data.advantage);
            },
```

My error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

```
:8000/api/advantages/store:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
2app.js:267 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/advantages/store 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:267
xhrAdapter @ app.js:118
dispatchRequest @ app.js:706
Promise.then (async)
request @ app.js:513
Axios.<computed> @ app.js:533
wrap @ app.js:966
createTask @ app.js:1773
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:9448
invoker @ app.js:9773
original._wrapper @ app.js:15126
```

Comment: The first thing you always do on a 500 Internal Server Error, is you go check the server’s error log!

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->HomepageAdvantages()
```

I'm not sure how you came up with this, as it will only work when you have a macro registered on the `Request` class. If so, please disregard this comment.

Otherwise, you'll need to explicitly call the model using `HomepageAdvantages::create()`.